# Noda Time WeekOfWeekYear starting Sunday and not Monday

Tags: c#, nodatime

While working with Noda Time I am trying to base some data on the `WeekOfWeekYear`,
What I have noticed is that the `WeekOfWeekYear` property changes on a Monday yet I need it to start on Sunday (using the ISO calendar). Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, ISO-8601 explicitly specifies that calendar weeks start on Monday - and "week of week year" is basically following ISO-8601.

If you want a different week and day numbering scheme, you'll currently have to create your own. (It may well not be terribly difficult, depending on what you need, but you'll need to do it yourself at the moment.) You should work out *exactly* what your requirements are in terms of how the first week of the year is determined though. For example, .NET provides a few options, none of which *quite* matches ISO-8601.

I'm just starting work on Noda Time 2.0 at the moment - if you think a more flexible date/week-year mapping API would be useful, please [file a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/issues/list) and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Jon is there a calender that does start the week on Sunday ?

Comment: @guyl: In reality, different cultures start the week on different days - but that's not modelled at all in Noda Time, and may also not be reflected in "week-of-year" rules, necessarily. (Bear in mind that different people within the same country may treat different days as "the start of the week.")